# gmtime_r & localtime_r() return the same results on vxworks

Tags: c, time, vxworks

I have a trouble about get the UTC time. With the test code, I found that both gmtime and localtime would return the same result

```
void testTimeLib()
{
    struct tm  utcTime, localTime;
    time_t now;
    char utcStr[80], localStr[80];

    time(&now);
    gmtime_r(&now, &utcTime);
    localtime_r(&now, &localTime);

    memset(utcStr, 0, sizeof(utcStr));
    strftime(utcStr, sizeof(utcStr), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &utcTime);

    memset(localStr, 0, sizeof(localStr));
    strftime(localStr, sizeof(localStr), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &localTime);

    printf("UTC Time\tutcTime <%s>\n", utcStr);
    printf("Local Time\tlocalTime <%s>\n", localStr);
}
```

the result is

```
-> testTimeLib
UTC Time    utcTime <2014-12-19T10:57:33>
Local Time  localTime <2014-12-19T10:57:33>
```

By checking the source code of gmtime_r and localtime_r, I found that __getZoneInfo called by localtime_r would return 0 which means the timezone is 0, actually the timezone should be GMT+8.

So my question is how I can set the  timezone to system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11785853/2410359 may help

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the `gmtime` and `localtime` function is that,
`gmtime` function will convert the calendar time into local time.
but the `localtime` function will convert the calendar time into broken-down time which is expressed as UTC.

You can use the `hwclock` command to set the time zone. only the super user has the permission to execute this command.
login as a super user and execute this command.

Comment: Thanks, the OS is vxworks so there is no such command, but I find that the timezone is set with putenv and now the problem is resovled

Comment: @Rgls if you are using linux, you can use the `hwclock` command